# OpenCV Blue Colonies Object Detection

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to use opencv for custom object detection. I've been using the AminAhmedi Windows Haarcascade trainer. The goal of the haarcascade file is to have it detect blue colonies on a petri dish.Every time I train the file my detection is way off. The images themselves are small and on a blueish background, however from what I had thought previously indicating that you are using a larger file on the GUI settings isn't an issue. Does anyone have a recommendation on the number of stages to use or any other information?

Tried training file using 20 stages, 32x3. The petri dish itself is contained inside an enclosure with white lighting along the bottom. The following is a snippet of the code I used:

stop_data = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r"C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cv2\data\blue1127_cascade.xml")

```
    found = stop_data.detectMultiScale(img_gray, 
                                       minSize =(20, 20))
    counter=0  
   
    amount_found = len(found)
     
    if amount_found != 0:
        print(img_rgb)
        print(found)
       
        
       
        for (x, y, width, height) in found:
            print("this")
            counter+=1
            
        self.label2.setText("Blue Colonies: "+ str(counter))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
What have you tried?  What research have you done?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.